# Unable to display XML file data in simple HTML file using jquery

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest, jquery-ajax

While running following code, getting CORS error and getting alert as "FAIL". What to do to make it success not fail.
Please suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>XML Data Load Test</body>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET" ,
                url: 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml',
                dataType: "xml" ,
                success: function() {
                     alert("Success");
                },
                error: function() {
                        alert('Fail');
                }       
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Getting error and alert as "FAIL"

Answer (score -1):

It's a cross-site request so you will need cross-origin resource sharing enabled. that is two headers requesters send Origin: URL  and the service should respond Access-Control-Allow-Origin: URL  header

It is simply explained on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Solution TIP: if this is a public resource and does not provide access control headers you will have to read it on your server and serve from there to your browser.